# how to close java.io.PipedInputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, jenkins, inputstream

I did a sequence of commands that caused my process to disconnect from a server and it left a thread in the TIMED_WAITING state.. specifically waiting on PipedInputStream@12304a39 (which I was supposed to supply with stdin but didn't) I know I can restart the server to solve this (or wait longer than I already have) but I am interested in a way I can kill this PipedInputStream succinctly.

My first approach was to find a way to reconnect to the input stream and then issue a .close() but I can only find ways to create new streams.. not connect/close existing ones.

Any ideas on how I could close it?

UPDATE:

I realize I need to close the corresponding PipedOutputStream now.

How can I locate which PipedOutputStream the PipedInputStream@12304a39 is connected to?

Then how would I connect to the PipedOutputStream to close it?

Comment: You need to close the corresponding `PipedOutputStream`. Although why you are using either is a mystery. They are only toys.

Comment: jenkins uses them.. I did a cli and web ui command and they conflicted. I found the one is waiting for a pipedinputstream.  I guess pipedoutputstream supplies it and stdin was supposed to supply that..

Could you elaborate on how to connect to and close the pipedoutputstream?  I have no information I can see on what Pipedoutputstream the pipedinputstream is connected to.

I can reword the question if needed

Comment: Err, `PipedOutputStream.close()`? But if you can't obtain either pipe, you're hosed, as it were.